# fastlane undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, fastlane, xcode11

I try integrate Fastlane to my project iOS but show the next error[image]

I am using Xcode 11

Comment: "no such file or directory" may be related.. I'd want to git rid of that error *first*, and then see if the latter remains.

Comment: thanks @user2864740, It worked